# Calculate statistics on +20millions records in Java

Tags: java, csv, stream, bigdata

I have csv file (600 MB) and 20 millions rows.
I need to read all this data, create list of java objects out of it, and calculate some metrics on objects field, such as average, median, max , total sum and other statistics. What is the best way of doing it in Java?
I tried simple .forEach loop and it took a while (20 min) to iterate over it .

**UPDATE:**
I user BufferReader to read the data and converting the csv file into List of Objects of some Java class. It's pretty fast.
 It's stuck for 20 minutes in **forEach** loop, where I trying to iterate over those 20 millions List of objects and divide them into 3 lists, depending on the values in the current object.
So basically,I iterate over whole list once, and I have if/else condition, where I check whether or not certain field in the objects equals to "X","Y" or "Z", and depending on the answer, separating those 20 mlns records into 3 lists.

Then, for those 3 lists I need to calculate different statistics: such as median, average, total sum etc

Comment: You can split the file and use multiple threads

Comment: there's not much that can be said if you're not willing to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Or you should try spring-batch, according to your requirements.

Comment: Nothing you've described should take more than 30 seconds.  We will need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having worked extensively with data amounts exceeding those 600Mb I can put out two statements:

- 600Mb is **not** a large amount of data, in particular if we are talking about tabular data;
- those amounts have nothing to do with BigData and are actually easily processable on conventional hardware in memory, which is the fastest option.

What you should do, however, is make sure that you read that data into column-wise continuous arrays and use methods operating directly on those continuous arrays of column-wise data.

Because it is a csv file, that is stored row-wise, you would be much better off reading it en-block into a byte array  and parse that into a column-wise pre-allocated representation.

Reading a block of 600Mb into memory on an SSD should be like a few seconds, parsing it will depend on you algorithm (but it is essential to be able to seek within that structure instantly). Memory wise you will use about triple of 600Mb, but with a 16Gb machine that should be a no-brainer.

So, do not rush for SQL or slicing files and do not instantiate every cell as a Java object. That is, in this **exceptional case**, you do not want a *list of Java objects*, you want `double[]` etc. You can do with `ArrayList`s though if you preallocate exact sizes. Other standard collections will kill you.

Having said all that, I would rather recommend `python` with `numpy` for the task than Java. Java is good with objects, and not as good with continuous memory blocks and corresponding operations. `C++` would do as well or even `R`.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest not loading all of the 600MB into RAM and using it as a Java Object.
As you stated this litteraly takes ages to load.

What you could do instead:

**Use SQL:**
Convert your data into a database, and on this database perform you search query(s). 
Don't loop over all objects in RAM. This would make your application very unperformant.

SQL is optimized for handling large amounts of data and performing querys on it.

Read more about Database Management in Java: [JDBC Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your program is simply running out of memory as you are adding stuff to a list. If you get close to the memory limit allocated to the JVM most of the time will be spent by the garbage collector trying to do what it can to prevent you running out of memory.

You should use a [fast](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) CSV library such as [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to iterate over each row and perform the calculations you need without storing all in memory. Use it like this:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings(); //configure the parser
parserSettings.selectFields("column3", "column1", "column10"); //only read values from columns you need

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

//use this if you just need plain strings
for(String[] row : parser.iterate(new File("/path/to/your.csv"))){
    //do stuff with the row
}

//or use records to get values ready for calculation
for(Record record : parser.iterateRecords(new File("/path/to/your.csv"))){
    int someValue = record.getInt("columnName");
    //perform calculations
}
```

Just store data in a huge list if for some reason you need to run through all rows more than once. In this case allocate more memory to your program with something like `-Xms8G -Xmx8G`. Keep in mind you can't have an `ArrayList` with size over `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so that's your next limit even if you have memory enough.

If you really need a list you can use use the parser like this:

```
List<Record> twentyMillionRecords = parser.parseAllRecords(new File("/path/to/your.csv"), 20_000_000);
```

Otherwise your best bet is to run the parser as many times as needed. The parser I suggested should take a few seconds to go through the file each time.

Hope this helps

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (apache 2.0 license)

Comment: I second the opinion on GC slowing things down. Try increasing JVM memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I bet majority of the time was spent reading the data. Having a BufferedReader should significantly speed things up.

Comment: Parallelizing the stream after reading the file should also help I suppose.

Comment: Hi! I already use BufferReader to read the data. And it's reading pretty fast. It's stuck  for 20 minutes in forEach loop, where I trying to iterate over those 20 millions records and divide them into 3 lists, depending on the values in the current object.
So basically,I iterate over whole list once, and I have if/else condition, where I check whether or not certain field in the objects equals to "X","Y" or "Z", and depending on the answer, separating those 20 mlns records into 3 lists

Comment: Try streaming your collection and filtering it's elements into 3 lists. hen do your calculations. Time the steps. This way you would know whether time is spent sorting your data or doing the calculations.

Comment: If reading your data is not the bottleneck then get a profiler and find out what is.